# How to set an array in a class in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, operator-overloading, setter

I'd like to store an array of numbers in a private variable of a class using a setter method, but am unsure how to.

The program requires a default constructor, and the other essential methods but for simplicity i've only provided the default constructor.

```cpp
class numberList{
public:
    numberList()
    {
        numberStore = new int[8];
    } // default constructor

    void setter() // not sure what goes here
    {
        //not sure what goes here
    }

private:
    int* numberStore;
};

int main()
{
    numberList list1;
    list1.setter(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
}
```

I'd like for the list1.setter() to take all the values to be put into the array. I think memcpy() could be used here, but am unsure.

I understand there's a concept of operator overloading, but am unsure how utilise this. Any help would be appreciated :-)

EDIT: the assignment requires me not to use standard libraries unfortunately :-(

Comment: If your array have a size that is known at compile-time, use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead. If the size is only known at run-time use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: The array has room for 8 numbers. Does the array need to set all 8 at one time, or can the caller set fewer? A variadic template or a `std::initializer_list` may be useful here. .

Comment: @RemyLebeau The array doesn't necessarily have to be full, but the use of standard libraries is prohibited by the teacher for this assignment

Comment: Is the number of elements in the list fixed?

Comment: Then first of all, unless the size is calculated at run-time, use an *actual* array (as in `int numberStore[8];`). Secondly, if it's okay to set only one element at a time then perhaps a function like `void set(unsigned index, int value);`

Comment: Do you need to set all the numbers at once or is it supposed to add all the numbers at the end of the array? And do you need to be able to store more than 8 numbers at any time?

Comment: @Jabberwocky the number isn't fixed, but i have an outline on how to resize the array to accommodate the number of elements. The issue I'm having is storing those elements into the private variable

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i was wondering if there was a way to set it all at once

Comment: The simplest way is to use an array as shown in [the answer by RoQuOTriX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57968925/440558). But you can also use [variadic function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic) (which I really don't recommend for beginners).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for pointing me in the direction of variadic functions - it looks like what i was aiming for, but the answer from RoQuOTriX looks to be the easiest to implement. Thank you for the guidance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your comment that you can't use the STL the solution is to use raw C-pointer arithemtics.

To your setter function you can give a `int* pointer` and the `number of elements`:

```
void setter(int* arr, int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        numberStore[i] = arr[i]
}
```

Then you can call your setter function in main() like this:

```
int main() {
    numberList list1;
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    list1.setter(arr, 7);
}
```

Comment: That looks very dangerous for `n > 8`

Comment: Thank you for this - I'll implement this into my solution. Looks simpler than variadic functions

Comment: @eike I have a method for extending the array that i can call in the setter, so should be no issue

Comment: @nutellasandwich Thats alright, but just the code from this answer alone would corrupt your heap for `n`s that are too large.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int* my_array = new int[10];

void setter(int* arr, int n)
{
    memcpy(&my_array[0], &arr[0], n * sizeof(int));
}


int main()
{
    int* arry = new int[10];
    for (int i=0; i< 10; i++)
    {
        arry[i] = i;
    }

    setter(arry, 10);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<(std::to_string(my_array[i]));
    }
}
```